# Maximum number of reads/second for a Blob storage file

Tags: c#, azure-blob-storage

Assume I decide to use Blob storage as a sort of web cache for web content like images. Is there any limit to maximum number of concurrent reads/ throughtput to a single web resource (web page/ file etc)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Maximum request rate per storage account:
>
> 20,000 requests per second(*)
>
> (*) If you need expanded limits for your storage account, please contact Azure Support. The Azure Storage team will review the request and may approve higher limits on a case by case basis. Both general-purpose and Blob storage accounts support increased capacity, ingress/egress, and request rate by request. For the new maximums for Blob storage accounts, see Announcing larger, higher scale storage accounts.

You can check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-subscription-service-limits#storage-limits) to get more info.